# Control the creating of new tags in Django-tagging

Tags: django, save, signals, tagging

I'm using Django-tagging in my project. It is required that the users can't create new tags if they don't have enough permission (they can still use the existing ones). I'm having a tag filed in the model of objects being tagged, which makes it very neat to work with tags but does not support the requirements. What I can think about involves:

1. Listen to the post_save signal and delete the new tags immediately
   after their creation, which seems to be a lot of extra work for the 
   database
2. Do some dirty work to Django-tagging's internal structure, like
   re-writing the clean method of tag field. This feels quite hacky and
   makes the code messy

It'll be perfect if the saving of new tags can be canceled in the pre_save signal of tags model. What is the best solution in this case?